# How to configure @SkipValidation by XML configuration in Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, annotations, xml-configuration

In Struts 2,

I am trying to skip validation on method base on XML configuration. 
As per my application I can not use annotation. So I cannot use `@SkipValidation` annotation. Is there any alternative for this?

I have one action class which has five methods `create`, `update`, `delete`, `search`, and `view`. I want to validate only two methods `create` and `update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure in the struts.xml package with interceptors

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor-stack name="validateWorkflowStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
<!-- ... whatever interceptors -->
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="excludeMethods">delete, search, view</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

then use action configuration

```
<action name="create" class="your.package.CreateAction" method="create">
    <result name="input">/path/to/form.jsp</result>
    <interceptor-ref name="validateWorkflowStack"/>
</action>
```

apply interceptor to each action that has a validation interceptor referenced explicitly on action or implicitly via `<default-interceptor-ref` on the package.

Comment: Why you are using the `basicStack`?

Comment: It doesn't contain the validation interceptor.

Comment: It doesn't contain a lot interceptors.

Comment: If a lot of interceptors is not necessary then better not use them.

Answer (score 2):

You must configure `validation` interceptor for your action to exclude methods names that you do not want to be validated.

```
<action name="..."  class="...">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="validation.excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,delete,search,view</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result>...</result>
</action>
```