# How to disable Struts Validation Interceptor?

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to build a javascript / ajax uploader which submits a form / file upload to an action. However when the form is submitted, the validation interceptor prevents my action from being run for some reason, and returns 'input' as the result. I'm not sure why, but I'd like it to stop.

How can I disable the validation interceptor only for `MyAction.execute()`? Here's my interceptors code from `struts.xml`:

```
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="appInit"
            class="com.example.myApp.interceptors.AppInit">
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="appDefault">
         <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>   
         <interceptor-ref name="appInit" />  
          <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
             <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
             <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
             <param name="params.excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*,submit</param>
          </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>
```

Comment: Care (whoever) to explain downvotes (to question and answers) and vote to close?

Comment: @leonbloy There's a particular user with an attitude problem; the ultimate solution is not to worry about it, 'cuz haters gonna hate.

Comment: Ehh he he.. Somebody down voted all of us!! And the absence of any contradicting point of view proves how much he understood the question or understands Struts 2 in general. I guess he too has a validation problem. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397240/how-to-configure-skipvalidation-by-xml-in-struts2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could go about bypassing validation for a specific Action. (I'm assuming you wouldn't want to disable the Interceptor for the entire application.)

```
<action name="MyAction" class="pkg.path.to.MyAction">
  <interceptor-ref name="appDefault">
    <param name="validation.excludeMethods">execute</param>
    <param name="workflow.excludeMethods">execute</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result>Success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The Validation interceptor only logs the errors. It's the Workflow interceptor that checks if any validation errors were logged and if yes redirects to the view mapped to the `input` result code.

***EDIT:***
<s>I think the nested stacks are causing trouble with the syntax for parameter override and I've never tried `<stack-name>.<interceptor-name>.excludeMethods` before. You may give it a try though.</s> *Update:* The above works. :)

But, instead of trying to exclude `execute()` you could rename it to `input()` (which is already on the exclude list) and add `method="input"` to your `<action>`. It kinda makes sense for a file upload too.

You could also override `validate()` for your Action (though I would personally prefer to do it declaratively through `struts.xml`)

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  ...
  @Override
  public void validate() {
    setFieldErrors(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck, same error as before. If I remove the `defaultStack` interceptor, then the form is submitted correctly, but is there a way to access the uploaded file and other form fields without the `defaultStack` interceptor?

Comment: No, no. Don't go that way. Try with explicit exclude on validation as well.

Comment: This thing works but in your case we have nested stacks here. Not sure if that's causing any troubles with the `<interceptor-name>.excludeMethods` syntax here.

Comment: nope, still returning `input` even for `<param name="workflow.excludeMethods">input,execute,validation</param>`

Comment: I meant adding `<param name="validation.excludeMethods">execute</param>` as well.

Comment: I'll need to have a look at your fileUpload form as well as the Action.

Comment: Okay, but which setting did you tweak to overcome this?

Comment: `<param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">2147483648</param>` and `<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2147483648" />`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way (as [a quick glance at the docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-TurningonValidation) reveal) is to place  the `AnnotationValidationInterceptor` in you stack, and annotate your method with `@org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.SkipValidation`

Comment: Any ideas how to do that without annotations?

Comment: +1. And considering the fact that in most cases one would extend [*struts-default.xml*](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-defaultxml.html) package, which **already** contains configuaration for the [*AnnotationValidationInterceptor*](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/validation/AnnotationValidationInterceptor.html), adding `SkipValidation` annotation is all you need. Quick and simple. Thanks for the tip )